# Determine network usage of a known process without root/elevation

Tags: networking, network-monitoring

My application is starting another process, and I'd like to keep track of how much data that new process has read/written from/to network sockets.

I've found tools like nethogs, but they require elevation to find the usage of arbitrary processes. It's also not something I can use to just get the running total as of 'right now' programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

It's not simple, but you could use `ptrace` on the child process and keep track of:

1. Which FDs are sockets.
2. Bytes in `read` and `write` calls.
3. Cross-reference the list in 1 and with sizes in 2 to determine bytes read/written on network sockets.